# How to call controller action from different project which don't return view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 projects MVCMembership and main web project which using membership and i need to get some date in controller which is in membership project from controller in my main web project.This is what i try:
this is from my membership controller

```
public ViewResult Index(int? index)
    {
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Group Admin"))
        {
            string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();

            var GroupUsers = RedirectToAction("UsersInGroup", "Account", new { Area = "" });
```

and this is action in my web project controller:

```
public MembershipUserCollection UsersInGroup()
    {
        var groupResultSet = db.aspnet_UsersInGroups.Where(u => u.UserID == (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey);
        var group = groupResultSet.Single().aspnet_Group;
        return group.Users;
    }
```

So this is not working because RedirectToAction returns RedirectToRouteResult.
Is there some way to do this?

To be more clear imagine you have 2 simple methods in one class

```
public somthing Method1()
{
    //doing something
    //call some other method
    var parm = Method2();
    //doing something whit parm
    return somethingelse;
}

public something Method2()
{
    //doing something
    return parm;
}
```

and now put that in context from up.Is that possible to do it?

Comment: So these projects exist in the same solution? There is an Area="", do you have an areas folder setup for one of these?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here and what is the exact problem that you are encountering. Could you please try to elaborate and reformulate it?

Comment: They are not in same solution i import dll of my membership in web project and i have area folder in it.I asking is there a way for me to call action from different project which don't do and get result back in action from which i call it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of performing this.

**The Bad**:
Actions in a controller are simply methods so you can call them directly you would need to create and instance of the controller and then call your method:

```
public ViewResult Index(int? index)
{
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Group Admin"))
    {
        string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
        var accountController = new AccountController()
        var GroupUsers = accountController.UsersInGroup();
```

**The Good**: Read up on wiring up a IOC container into your MVC application, remove the method you require from the controller and place it into a service and inject the service into your controller.

```
 public YourController:Controller
 {
     private IMembershipService  _membership 
     public YourController(IMembershipService membership)
     {
         _membership = membership;
     } 

     public ViewResult Index(int? index)
     {
       if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Group Admin"))
       {
           string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();

           var GroupUsers = _membership.UsersInGroup();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can call controller from other project you can just use Response.Redirect(

```
public EmptyResult Home()
  {
     Response.Redirect("http://YourDoimein.com/Controller/Action");
  }
```

Comment: Well if i do that how i return result which type is MembershipUserCollection to action from which i call it?

Comment: I mean,I don't know if that is even possible that is why I ask.I know that i can redirect to that action,but I can return that result back.

Comment: Tou can use EmptyResult in Action